# JS: need explanation about setTimeout() behavior

Tags: javascript, range, settimeout

I have 2 button. First one runs the reminder, another stops it:

```
<input type="range" id="range" min="1" max="480" onInput="syncValues('intrvl',this);" />
<input type="text" id="intrvl" value="0.07" onInput="syncValues('range',this);" />
```

Here is the script (the live version is accessible on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/9kslSw6lyflIkMTanCrA):

```
function syncValues(inpToId, inpFrom) {
  if (!inpFrom) inpFrom = document.getElementById('intrvl');
  document.getElementById(inpToId).value = inpFrom.value;
}
window.onload = function() {
  syncValues('range');
  var makeDecition = (function() {
    var tm,
      stp = false,
      gotm = false,
      sttm = function(cancel) {
        var min = document.getElementById('intrvl').value;
        tm = setTimeout(makeDecition, min * 60 * 1000);
      };
    return function(cancel) {
      console.dir(cancel);
      if (cancel) {
        stp = false;
        clearTimeout(tm);
      } else {
        if (gotm) {
          if (!stp)
            if (!confirm("Go on?")) gotm = null;
        } else {
          stp = false;
          gotm = true;
        }
        if (gotm !== null) sttm();
      }
    };
  }());
  document.getElementById('start').onclick = function(event) {
    makeDecition();
    event.currentTarget.disabled = true;
  };
  document.getElementById('stop').onclick = function(event) {
    makeDecition();
    document.getElementById('start').disabled = false;
    makeDecition(true);
  };
};
```

I want that after clicking on the Stop button the timeout will be removed and script will terminated immediately. But it show me confirm istead. I checked what happens after calling makeDecition(true) and found that the function doesn't get the **cancel** param, first, as mentioned above, it calls confirm and only after it the param comes. 
Can anybody explain how to fix it and why it happens?

Comment: Your code in the "stop" onclick first calls `   makeDecition();` with no parameter; that looks exactly like the thing that's supposed to trigger the `confirm()`.

Comment: oops... you are right,  shame on me :( Make your comment as an answer,   I will apply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a stray no-argument call to your "makeDecition" function at the beginning of your "stop" handler :)